# What are the parsing algorithms for programmed grammars?

Tags: parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar, regular-language, context-sensitive-grammar

I want to know what are the parsing algorithms used for parsing programmed grammars. Any Links , blogs or anything where i can read about programmed grammars and there parsing algorithms except IEEE research papers ?

Comment: What's wrong with research papers? If you're going to go headlong into more niche areas of CS you should be prepared to read academic papers...

Comment: Actually, I have read some of them already but didn't find anything specific to the programmed grammars.

Comment: I've done a lot of parsing over the years and am unfamiliar with the phrase "programmed grammers" or "parsing-programmed grammars".   What you need to do is find a source that defines this term and read the corresponding paper.   You might be surprised, but if your term is technically accurate, an IEEE or ACM technical paper is likely to hold the most authoritative answer.  Based on my unfamiliarity with the term, it might be that you have somehow mangled the name of thing of interest to you.  Where did you encounter the term, and why is it interesting?  (There's many, many parser types).

Comment: Thanks Ira! But I got this as my assignment topic, I didn't invented it. I found some papers on Programmed Grammars from "google" but nothing is there regarding their parsing algorithms. From my search I am observing that this not among the conventional subjects of Grammars, very few people know about this. Please keep looking and tell me if you find something..

Comment: The classic method for finding the right papers is to take the ones you have that mention your topic, and check the references.  Good papers contain references to earlier, more basic material, usually referenced in an opening paragraph in a sentence like "Much work has been done on Parsing Programmed Grammars {ref 23}..."  Go read the referenced papers, and follow *their* references.  Google Scholar is now a pretty good to track this backward quickly.  We all have our learning experiences; this one's yours.

Comment: Thank You,Ira!! No one gives such advice for free, nice talking to you.

Comment: Well, well, you haven't mangled the phrase.  A google search for "programmed grammers" turns up, on the first pages of hits, "A NEW NORMAL FORM FOR PROGRAMMED GRAMMARS WITH ... www.feec.vutbr.cz/EEICT/2012/sbornik/.../12-xvrabe01.pdfShare", complete with the (as predicted) sentence in the opening paragraphs "In the formal language theory, programmed grammars have been thoroughly investigated (see [1, 2, 4–6, 8, 10]...".  This suggests you aren't trying very hard. Happy reading.

Comment: I should clarify your doubt about my hard work, that I have read this paper already and refer their references also but they have nothing to say about "Parsing Algorithms for Programmed Grammars". Some talk about "programmed grammars" while other about "parsing algo's" of some other grammars.

Comment: OK, good for you.  Follow the references.  Eventually you'll get to a paper that contains the basic ideas and algorithms.

Comment: "except IEEE research papers"... so ACM is allowed?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's explained well in *[The power of programmed grammars with graphs from various classes](http://www.jamc.net/contents/table_contents_view.php?Len=&idx=522#)*:

> A context-free grammar is specified as a quadruple `G = (N, T, S, P)`, where `N`
>   is a finite non-empty set called the nonterminal alphabet, `T` is a finite non-empty set called the terminal alphabet `(N ∩ T = ∅), S ∈ N` is the start symbol, and `P`
>   is a finite subset of `N × (N ∪ T)∗` called the set of rules. Rules are also named
>   as productions.
>
> A programmed grammar (without appearance checking) is a six-tuple `G =
>   (N, T, S, Lab, P, PG)` where `N , T and S` are specified as in a context-free grammar, `Lab` is an alphabet (of labels), `P` is a finite set of context-free rules called
>   the set core productions, and PG is a finite set of triples `r = (q, p, σ)`, where
>   `q ∈ Lab` is the label of `r, p ∈ P` is a context-free production called the core
>   production of `r`, and `σ` is a subset of `Lab` and is termed the success field of `r`.
>   The elements of `PG` are called the rules of `G`.
>
> The language `L(G)` generated by a programmed grammar `G` specified as above
>   is defined as the set of all words `w ∈ T∗` such that there is a derivation
>   `S = w0 =⇒r1 w1 =⇒r2 w2 =⇒r3 . . . =⇒rk wk = w,`
>   where `k ≥ 1` and, for `1 ≤ i ≤ k, wi−1 = wi−1 Ai wi−1` and `wi = wi−1 vi wi−1`
>   for some words `wi−1 , wi−1 ∈ (N ∪ T)∗ , ri = (qi , Ai → vi , σi)` and, for `i < k,
>   qi+1 ∈ σi`.

*Excuse the lack of LaTeX.*

In a similar way that [Ogden's Lemma is stronger than the Pumping Lemma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12888243/1240268) (because of markings), the concept of programmed grammar is stricter than context-free because of these labellings.

Comment: As I said, I already refered these papers but still it does not explain anything about parsing algorithm.Thank you!!

Comment: The third paragraph essentially describes a parsing algorithm, I'll write up a bit more later.